# Does roboearth plan to support newer ROS distros eventually?

Tags: ros-groovy, roboearth, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current code base and tutorials [only support Fuerte](http://wiki.ros.org/roboearth_stack).

Are there plans to actively support newer releases?

I found [this related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/71938/error-while-running-roboearth-on-groovy/) about porting the Fuerte code to Groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97931/does-roboearth-plan-to-support-newer-ros-distros-eventually?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no plans to port the object recording packages to Groovy in the near future (due to lack of time).

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-11-21**:
How about the distant future? We have students working on object recognition with Hydro on Precise. Right now roboearth is not an option. Will it ever be?